# Replacing globe lights to candelabras and need to extend wire

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, socket, rewire

Im changing my globes to candelabras. I bought the extension sockets to replace the short ones to fit the candelabra but Im pretty sure the wires aren’t going to be long enough to stretch the length of my new sockets. Any ideas that aren’t too hard?
[image]

Comment: Can you add a few pictures of the fixtures, globes, etc.., so we can see what you see?

Comment: Added photo now. Hope this helps.

Comment: Ummm, do you have any experience with complete fixture rewire? Maybe doesn't fit your criteria of not being "too hard", but I don't see any other viable option. Wire splices have to be inside of a listed enclosure...